# display diffrent images depending on time

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a sort of homepage with some code to change the background based on the time. My problem is: it only checks the time when the page first loads, I need it to be constantly checking for it. Here is my code, please help.

```
  var today2 = new Date();
  var h2 = today2.getHours();

  if (h2 > 18) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('cityatnight2.jpg')";
  }    
  else if (h2 < 9) {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('sunrise2.jpg')";
  }  
  else {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('homescreen3.jpg')";
  }
```

Comment: User `setInterval`.

Comment: This will depend with what frequence your bg will change, I mean, each hour, each minutos so, you should initialize a setTimeout function to check the hour with the frequent needed

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```js
var changeBg = function(num){

  if (num > 18) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else if (num < 9) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }

  else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }

}



setInterval(function(){
  var today2 = new Date();
  var h2 = today2.getSeconds(); //edit here. sec -> hour.
  
  console.log(h2)
  
  changeBg(h2);


},1000) //and edit here. 1000 means 1sec
```

Comment: This changes it based on the current number of seconds.  The OP changed it based on the current hour.  Not sure why you would suggest that change.

Comment: @DarrinCullop Because I wanted to show quick changing. As I commented, he need to edit sec -> hour.

Comment: thanks! wouldnt havethought of it, but i did change the secinds to hours, but seconds helped me trouble shoot it so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `setInterval` command.  It allows you to specify that code run at a given interval.  For example, to run every hour, you could do this:

```
function SetBackground()
{
    var today2 = new Date();
    var h2 = today2.getHours();

    if (h2 > 18) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('cityatnight2.jpg')";
    }
    else if (h2 < 9) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('sunrise2.jpg')";
    }
    else {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('homescreen3.jpg')";
    }
}

// 1 Hour Interval
window.setInterval(SetBackground, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Read more about that function here:   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp